# How to handle an interrupted HTTP connection in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, connection, request

Suppose I create a `HTTPWebRequest`, call its `GetResponse()` and start reading from the response stream. If the connection is interrupted while reading from the stream, do I have to wait for it to time out, or can I know right away that something's gone wrong? No exception is thrown when I interrupt the connection (e.g. I disconnect my computer from the network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the situation.

In general you'll need to be prepared for both situations (immediate and late interruption).
If, for example, the server disconnects you, you'll know relatively quickly.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus for the kinds of errors that can occur (the `WebRequest` classes throw `WebException`s on errors)

You have a variety of options:

- Use the async methods (`BeginGet...` and `EndGet...`) and model your application around this. Basically you'll be notified "at some point" if there was a success or error. Do something else in the meantime
- If you want absolute control you can specify a `ReadTimeout` on the acquired stream (See comment on the other answer, set `Timeout` on the request as well). Re-try or whatever.
- Just wait

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to worry if the request is interrupted or not.

You can specify explicit timeout as follows.
If its interrupted you will get exception.

```
     try
     {
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 3000;
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
           //do stuff
        }
     }
     catch (Exception exception)
     {
        exception.ToLog();
     }
```

Comment: The time-out will not cover conditions that occur after having acquired the response stream afaik. So you can still time out while reading the response stream

Comment: I'm using this (changing stream.ReadTimeout instead), but obviously I can't limit it too much, or it would time out too easily.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you have to wait for the timeout